# Gradle build successful but no app installed on android device

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I am working on android kotlin room basic app. I was able to successfully gradle build on Android Dolphin but the app does not install on a physical android phone. How can I install the app on the phone?
Stack trace:

```
1:01:09 PM: Executing 'app:assemble'...

Executing tasks: [app:assemble] in project C:\Users\E6400\AndroidStudioProjects\android-basics-kotlin-sql-basics-app

> Task :app:createDebugVariantModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createReleaseVariantModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:buildKotlinToolingMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsReleaseKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:kaptReleaseKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:lintVitalReportRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dexBuilderRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compressReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:optimizeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:sdkReleaseDependencyData UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeReleaseAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeReleaseSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createReleaseApkListingFileRedirect UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:assembleRelease
> Task :app:assemble

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 45s
73 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 72 up-to-date

Build Analyzer results available
1:02:00 PM: Execution finished 'app:assemble'.
```

Comment: Does the app run on the emulator?
Do you get any error in the logcat?
Have you activated developer options and USB debugging on the physical device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to go into developer mode of the phone. Go to Settings -> About Phone -> look for Build Version. Tap build version about 8 times. This will enable developer mode on the phone.

Now go into the developer mode and scroll down and toggle on the USB Debugging. Plug your device in the computer while Android studio is open. When you plug in the phone you will want to allow file transfer. Then Android Studio will send a message to the phone and you will select Allow and check the box that says remember choice.

Once you have completed that Android should detect the device in the drop down under devices. If you don't see it go to the AVD and look for physical device.

If it does auto detect, then you run the app and it will show on the device instead of the emulator.

Some Android phones may be different in getting to the build version. So just get to build version then everything else will be following the prompts.

Also your phone will have to be the same API version or higher. Example, Android 10 based API will not install on an Android 9 based phone. Be sure the API are equivalent or better.

Comment: My android phone is already visible as AVD (debug mode) but for some mysterious reason the gradle build fails to install app without any errors. I am using Android 9 device, the compilesdk is 33 with minTarget 19.

Comment: @KaleabWoldemariam it may be a bug within Android Studio. My emulator doesn't work half the time and i have to use a physical device, which i do all the time anyway. However, my Android is a 12. The only thing I can think of, is test this theory and build a new project with the same setup but just the default UI, and see if it works. If it does then you could have a bug in your code somewhere. That has happened to me before.

Comment: What eventually worked was I deleted some apps from my phone, and made sure that the configuration was 'app'.

Comment: @KaleabWoldemariam I am glad it worked out. I have 3 devices I use for testing. So once I complete an app and push it to Play Store I delete the development app. So I would of never thought of the cache portion of the app. That's a note I have noted in case I run into the same problem